# Traffic flow $u_{t}+(1-2 u) u_{x}=0$ with arctan initial data (Salsa, Ex. 4.4)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

This problem is from Sandro Salsa's book (1), page 201.

> *Example 4.4.* Consider the initial value problem
> $$
> \left\{\begin{array}{l}
> u_{t}+(1-2 u) u_{x}=0 \\
> u(x, 0)=\frac{1}{2} \arctan (\pi x) .
> \end{array}\right. \tag{4.45}
> $$
> We have $q(u)=u-u^{2}$, $q'(u)=1-2 u$, $q''(u)=-2$, and $g(\xi)=\frac{1}{2} \arctan (\pi \xi)$, $g'(\xi)=\pi / 2\left(1+\pi^{2} \xi^{2}\right)$. Therefore, the function
> $$
> z(\xi)=-q''(g(\xi)) g^{\prime}(\xi)=\frac{\pi}{\left(1+\pi^{2} \xi^{2}\right)}
> $$
> has a maximum at $\xi_{M}=0$ and $z(0)=\pi$. The breaking-time is $t_{s}=1 / \pi$ and
> $$
> x_{s}=q'(g(\xi_{M})) t_{s}+\xi_{M}=1 / \pi .
> $$
> Thus, the shock curve starts from $(1 / \pi, 1 / \pi)$. For $0 \leq t<1 / \pi$ the solution $u$ is smooth and implicitly defined by the equation
> $$
> G(x, t, u)=u-\frac{1}{2} \arctan [\pi x-\pi(1-2 u) t]=0 . \tag{4.46}
> $$
> After $t=1 / \pi$, equation (4.46) defines $u$ as a multivalued function of $(x, t)$ and does not define a solution anymore.

The book says that:

> We have to insert a shock wave into the multivalued graph [in Fig. 4.16], in a way that the conservation law is preserved. We will see that the correct insertion point is prescribed by the Rankine-Hugoniot condition. It turns out that this corresponds to cutting off from the multivalued profile the two **equal area** lobes $A$ and $B$ [as described in Fig. 4.17], at time $t=0.7$ (*G. B. Whitham equal area rule*).

"Indeed, due to the odd symmetry in the variables $x, u$ of $G$ with respect to the point $(t, 0)$, we have here $x=s(t)=t$."

I have one question:

1. I do not understand  How do you get $x=s(t)=t$ with Whitham equal area rule?

I would be grateful for your help.

---

(1) S. Salsa, *Partial Differential Equations in Action: From Modelling to Theory*, 3rd ed., Springer, 2016. [doi:10.1007/978-3-319-31238-5](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-31238-5)